# Playing audio in iOS devices via Appium

Tags: ios, selenium, selenium-webdriver, audio, appium

I am testing a Speech recognition app for iOS through appium in remote environment (Selenium Grid), running test from windows machine. I am able to perform different actions using appium. But there is no option to play Audio in iOS devices.
Any suggestion/solution available below scenarios.

1. Playing audio through Appium. OR
2. Executing shell script for playing audio in mac machine via appium?

Comment: I don't understand the use case.. You want to make the device play some audio file that your Speech recognition app is going to "hear"?

Comment: Yes. And also running tests from remote env.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.